# Parental Controls flooded system.log with errors

Tags: macos, logs, parental-controls

I was digging around for fun, and found that my `system.log` was ***flooded*** with errors. Here is the output of `sudo cat system.log | tail -8`:

```
Mar 19 15:33:06 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[113]: -[ActivityTracker appDidLaunchOrBecomeFront:launched:] [1844:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 UserInfo=0x34dd00 "The file “events.data” couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format."
Mar 19 15:33:57 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[113]: -[ActivityTracker appDidLaunchOrBecomeFront:launched:] [1844:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 UserInfo=0x12a6d0 "The file “events.data” couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format."
Mar 19 15:34:02 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[113]: -[ActivityTracker appDidLaunchOrBecomeFront:launched:] [1844:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 UserInfo=0x129b50 "The file “events.data” couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format."
Mar 19 15:34:17 THE-COMPUTER Safari[155]: __CFServiceControllerBeginPBSLoadForLocalizations timed out while talking to pbs
Mar 19 15:34:29 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[113]: -[ActivityTracker saveData] [411:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 UserInfo=0x3451c0 "The file “events.data” couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format."
Mar 19 15:34:37 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[113]: -[ActivityTracker appDidLaunchOrBecomeFront:launched:] [1844:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 UserInfo=0x3535d0 "The file “events.data” couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format."
Mar 19 15:34:42 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[113]: -[ActivityTracker appDidLaunchOrBecomeFront:launched:] [1844:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 UserInfo=0x12bbb0 "The file “events.data” couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format."
Mar 19 15:35:56 THE-COMPUTER parentalcontrolsd[113]: -[ActivityTracker appDidLaunchOrBecomeFront:launched:] [1844:ezra] -- Got an error when saving MOC: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=259 UserInfo=0x34aee0 "The file “events.data” couldn’t be opened because it isn’t in the correct format."
```

These seem to be messages from Parental Controls, but what do they mean? Also, they are going on all the time. Could anyone shed some light??

Comment: It might help to know which OS X version you are talking about.

Comment: @SethNoble Snow Leopard (10.6.6)

Comment: If possible, try updating to 10.6.8.  I don't know if that will fix it, but it will at least provide a better baseline.

Comment: I have the same issue on 10.6.7. There are about 10 new messages per second. I can't even read my logs anymore.

Answer (score 1):

I had to remove the account with Parental Controls and stop using that feature. It became a CPU melter in my case. You may also want to upgrade to Mac OS X 10.6.8.

Answer (score 0):

There is a sandboxing error where the process responsible for writing log files is running into the inability to write those files.

Three things could help:

1. Modifying your logging protocol to exclude that sender
2. Turning off that part of parental controls
3. Upgrading to a newer OS
4. Filing a bug report with Apple to get the underlying logic error corrected.